# Error de cors con mis imágenes en laravel

Tags: php, laravel, cors

tengo un error que no lo he podido solucionar tengo una app hecha en ionic y consulto unas imágenes de una backend hecho en laravel, pero al momento de querer mostrar las imágenes en la app me sale un error de cors, ya agrergue fruitcake/laravel-cors y la configure pero me sigue fallando, solo falla con las imagenes no falla con los api que consumo del mismo backend.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El mensaje de error va como texto por favor

Comment: No se si estàs trabajando con un API, si es asì te hace falta esta parte [EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")] ese error te sale porquè quieres acceder de una URL a otra y recibir respuesta, como tal ningùn navegador te va a dejar si antes otorgar permisos

Comment: No nada, en la descripción del error especifico que solo para cuando quiero acceder a las imágenes en cambio a los api me accede sin ningún problema